# What is different Between "IWebHost" and "IWebHostBuilder" in Dot Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I cant run application after publish when using IWebHostBuilder but Its fine and working while developing build and run.

On the other hand when using IWebHost Its fine in both in development time and on the server.

I want to know the difference between this and valid resource describing this.

Note : Its occurs only when I Use MVC Framework or DbContext

This is working fine after deployment on server

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

This is not working on server (after deployment) but fine on development run

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```